# Why isn't my java code able to create multiple instances of an object?

Tags: java, object

If anyone knows Java well I would really appreciate the help. Looking to create two or more instances of the `Employee` object. As you can see in the `Main` class I have successfully created the first object "Susan" but when I try to add "Jake" it doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out why. I have added the console output of my test code for some clarity. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Employee {
    String name;
    LinkedList<Employee> employees;

    public Employee(String ename){
        name = ename;
        employees = new LinkedList<Employee>();
        System.out.println("The newest employee is: " + ename);
    }

    void addSub(Employee subName){
        employees.add(subName);
        System.out.println("Adding " + subName + " to the employee list");
    }

    void getEmployee(int num){
        employees.get(num);
    }

    void print(){
        printHelper(0);
    }

    void printHelper(int level){
        for(int i = 0; i < level; i++){
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
        System.out.println(name + "\n");
        level++;
        for(int j = 0; j < employees.size(); j++){
            System.out.println(employees.get(j));
            printHelper(level);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Employee susan = new Employee("Susan");
        Employee jake = new Employee("Jake"); //HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP
        susan.addSub(jake);
        
        susan.print();
    }
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
CONSOLE OUTPUT

The newest employee is: Susan

The newest employee is: Jake

Adding Employee@299a06ac to the employee list

Susan

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: What makes you think it hasn't worked?  It says "The newest employee is: Jake" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is code which gives the result you expected.

```
public class Employee {
    String name;
    List<Employee> subEmployees;

    public Employee(String employeeName){
        System.out.println("The newest employee is: " + employeeName);
        name         = employeeName;
        subEmployees = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    void addSub(Employee subName){
        System.out.println("Adding " + subName.name + " to the employee list");
        subEmployees.add(subName);
    }

    void print(){
        printHelper(0);
    }

    void printHelper(int level){
        for(int i = 0; i < level; i++){
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
        System.out.println(name);
        if(subEmployees.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }
        for (Employee employee : subEmployees) {
            level = level + 1;
            employee.printHelper(level);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Employee susan = new Employee("Susan");
        Employee jake  = new Employee("Jake"); //HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP
        Employee bevan  = new Employee("Bevan"); //HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP
        jake.addSub(bevan);
        susan.addSub(jake);
        susan.print();
    }
}
```

And the console output is as below.

```
The newest employee is: Susan
The newest employee is: Jake
The newest employee is: Bevan
Adding Bevan to the employee list
Adding Jake to the employee list
Susan
    Jake
        Bevan
```

Comment: Thank you so so much!!